# Which German word contains the most ä, ö, ü, and ß in any variation?

Tags: vocabulary, umlaut, eszett, curiosity

I'm German and residing in France. When I was asked the following question the only word which came into my mind was *Gesäß.*

Which German word contains the most ä, ö, ü, and ß in any variation?

Are there others which contain more than two umlauts and ß? Not "zusammengesetzte Substantive" please and only words from the Duden.

Comment: `rückwärts`, `äußerst` each have two. `Möbelträgerfüße` has all four but is a compound noun. How about an entire sentence? `Völlerei lässt grüßen`:)

Comment: One of Michael Ende's books has the title: "Der satanarchäolügenialkohöllische Wunschpunsch" The adjective in question does not abide the rules of compounding words, so one might say it's not compound. But unfortunately, it's also not in the Duden.

Comment: I would suggest not looking for the word with the most äöüß, but with the largest ratio of them (and strictly longer than two letters).

Comment: @Earthliŋ: "süß" has a 2/3 ratio and 3 letters, which is more than 2. I don't think you can beat that.

Comment: @celtschk Quite unlikely, yes. But [Süßöl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96le#Fette_.C3.96le) comes very close and needs a _Süßölgefäß_ to be contained in. Too bad they are both compound nouns and hence do not qualify for an answer.

Comment: It’s interesting how both the umlauts and the ß are considered characteristic for German, however there aren’t that many non-compounds that contain more than one of each. There should be no stem with two ß for example. Finnish on the other hand can (and will) contain a lot more ä and ö (they use y instead of ü), e.g. *ääntään* (‘her voice’ in partitive case).

Comment: @Jan   ß  is anyway only a typographical phenomenon (and has nothing to do with the phonology or so of German). The letter is based on a once usual ligature for double s in printing.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I know. Why are you telling me?

Answer (score 37):

Mit grep finde ich in einem Wörterbuch:

```
egrep ".*[äöüßÄÖÜ].*[äöüß].*[äöüß].*[äöüß]" ~/lib/dicts/utf-german 

Fußgängerübergänge
Größenmaßstäbe
größenordnungsmäßig
```

also 3 Vierlinge, aber leider alle mit einer Wiederholung. Längere sind nicht verzeichnet, aber da man im Deutschen beliebig lange Substantive kombinieren kann wäre "Fußgängerübergangsmörtel" ein Wort, in dem jeder Umlaut und das Eszet einmal vorkommt.

Comment: Durch das schwammige "keine zusammengesetzten Substantive" Kriterium (fallen auch zusammengesetzte Adjektiv darunter?) fallen die möglicherweise raus.

Comment: @dirkt: Oh, dieses Kriterium muss ich übersehen haben. Ohne Zusammensetzungen wird es natürlich schwierig.

Answer (score 16):

I found some word with three characters

- (un)[verhältnismäßig](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/verh%C3%A4ltnism%C3%A4%C3%9Fig), [Verhältnismäßigkeit](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Verh%C3%A4ltnism%C3%A4%C3%9Figkeit)
- [Präzisionsmeßgerät](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Pr%C3%A4zisionsme%C3%9Fger%C3%A4t) (old spelling, and perhaps "zusammengesetzte Substantiv")
- [Lückenbüßer](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/L%C3%BCckenb%C3%BC%C3%9Fer)
- [Übergröße](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/%C3%9Cbergr%C3%B6%C3%9Fe)
- [Müßiggänger](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/M%C3%BC%C3%9Figg%C3%A4nger)
- [außerplanmäßig](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/au%C3%9Ferplanm%C3%A4%C3%9Fig)

Some more without a check in the Duden:

- Einflußgröße
- Gefäßschädigung
- Meßgröße
- Rückäußerung
- Rückstöße
- blütenübersät
- flächenmäßig
- gefühlsmäßig
- geschäftsmäßig
- größtmöglich
- rüstungsmäßig
- übergroßzügig
- überläßt
- übermäßig

Some with four characters, but with some problems:

- Größenmaßstäbe - composed word, plural and not in the Duden
- [Grünflügelbülbül](http://www.zootierliste.de/?klasse=2&ordnung=222&familie=22206&art=21103339) - not in the Duden, it is a bird name - [Mountain Streaked Bulbul](http://orientalbirdimages.org/search.php?Bird_ID=1684)

Comment: All of your examples are compound words, although the OP only excluded compound nouns.

Comment: I think, the words with "-mäßig" (like "gefühlsmäßig") aren't compounds. "-mäßig" is in this case a suffix (like "-los" or "-bar" in "gefühlslos" and "fühlbar"). ("mäßig" as single word has another meaning!) So: these words with "-mäßig" are correct answers!

Answer (score 3):

In Duden:

```
$ aspell -d de dump master | aspell -l de expand > de.dict
$ grep ä de.dict | grep ö | grep ü | wc --lines
1
$ grep ä de.dict | grep ö | grep ü | cut -d \  -f1
tränenüberströmt
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just writing my diary for yesterday, when my wife made Käsespätzle for our evening meal.
It made me wonder about any other words that may have more than one umlaut, and therefore I landed here.

Answer (score 0):

Ein weiter Vierling: Eine Ausländerin hat einmal in einem Interview mit dem SZ-Magazin geagt, sie habe im Deutschkurs des Goethe-Instituts gelernt, dass

> Heizölrückstoßabdämpfung

das längste deutsche Wort sei, in dem sich kein einziger Buschtabe wiederholt (Prüfe, wer möchte)
Das Wort ist zwar zusammengesetzt und steht nicht im Duden, wenn sich das Goethe-Institut aber darauf bezieht, finde ich, dass ich es hier nennen kann.